# Angular 2+ using ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/

But If I copy the code it doesn't work. It displays:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of

```
<ul>
<li>Static List Template</li>
</ul>
```

These properties remain undefined:

```
@ContentChild(CardItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) cardItemTemplate;
@ContentChild(ListItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) listItemTemplate;
```

Edit: The previous plnkr was incorrect. Forgot to save. See this one:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/b9kdTXoe8ZRqnuSv?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ContentChild, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cardItem]'
})
export class CardItemDirective {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[listItem]'
})
export class ListItemDirective {}


@Component({
  selector: 'card-or-list-view',
  template: `
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="mode">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'card'">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cardItemTemplate"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ul *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItemTemplate"></ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </ng-container>
  `
})
export class CardOrListViewComponent {

  @Input() items: any[] = [];

  @Input() mode: 'card' | 'list' = 'card';

  // Read in our structural directives as TemplateRefs
  @ContentChild(CardItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) cardItemTemplate;
  @ContentChild(ListItemDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) listItemTemplate;

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-usage',
  template: `
    <card-or-list-view
        [items]="items"
        [mode]="mode">
      <div cardItem>
        Static Card Template
      </div>
      <li listItem>
        Static List Template
      </li>
    </card-or-list-view>
`
})
export class UsageExample {
  mode = 'list';
  items = [
    {
      header: 'Creating Reuseable Components with NgTemplateOutlet in Angular',
      content: 'The single responsibility principle...'
    } // ... more items
  ];
}
```

Comment: The plunker you provided does not seem to relate to the question. Wrong link?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save. Edited my post with new link

Comment: Hey @UrbKr, I'm the author of that tutorial. There is in fact a typo. The static templates should have an asterisk because you can only access a `TemplateRef ` in two ways - [Via a directive placed on a <ng-template> element (or directive prefixed with *)](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef). Without it, the `ContentChild` will be undefined. I'll work on getting the tutorial updated soon. Cheers

Comment: @MarkKennedy 
Ok, great!
Perhaps this isn't the right place to ask, but do you have any thoughts on the pattern you outline in your tutorial and the one described here:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
Do you think it's for different purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your template in an `<ng-template>` or use the [asterisk-prefix syntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix) so that you can use it with a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive):

```
<ng-template listItem>
  <li>
    Static List Template
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

or shorter:

```
<li *listItem>
  Static List Template
</li>
```

Note: You'll have two nested `li` tags with this. Maybe not what you want...

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odzrt6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This works! Has something changed, because the tutorial doesn't seem to do any of those things. Or perhaps it was a mistake.

Comment: I think it's a slight mistake in the tutorial. If you follow the rest of it, then they will add the asterisk later.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the ContentChildren will always be undefined because they are never being defined. ngTemplateOutlet takes a templateRef or a component as a param which is never being defined anywhere in your code since your content children never render. Personally I prefer going to ViewContainerRef/ComponentFactoryResolver route: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

This gives you more granular control over the component and allows you programatically set the @Input variables as well. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the other answer, because it fixed the code directly. Still, I'll check out the alternative as well.

Comment: Do you use this method for all cases?

Comment: Yes only because i have created a reusable directive i can use so going the ngTemplate route doesnt save me any extra work.